# Displaying ready pivoted data in a graph - SQL Server Data Tools/BIDS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, graph, bids

I have some ready pivoted data in SSRS that I wish to display as a graph, i.e. I have 13 columns (product and then one column for each month) and a values row below.

Because the data is 'pre pivoted' into columns rather than rows I'm struggling create a graph that displays as it would in excel, i.e. because each month is a column/field they are effectively different series in the graph, therefore the horizontal axis isn't  as months, they are displaying as numbers (the chart data bars are fine).

Has anyone got any ideas with regards to how I could fix this?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Is this not what you want? Change the axis around using the series properties

[image: sss]